# How to download ".xlsx" file using FTPWebRequest through C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, xlsx, ftpwebrequest

I've tried everything to get an xlsx file to download through an FTPWebRequest -- to no avail.  I've tried converting the file type from xlsx to xls and even to csv, but it just gives me a file full of indecipherable symbols.  All file types download through Chrome as expected with no exceptions with the code provided, except for xlsx files.

When I try to download an xlsx file using this code, I get the following error from excel: "We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want us to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click 'Yes'."  Upon clicking on 'Yes', the message "Microsoft Excel was attempting to open and repair the file.  To start this process again, choose Open and Repair from the Open file dialog."  Proceeding with those instructions just creates an endless loop of the same messages.

Any help on this would be great!  Also, I've tried changing the content-type to
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" and "application/vnd.ms-excel", and neither works.

```
string ftpfilename = "ftp://ftpserverinfo/randomfilename.xlsx";                                
string filename = "randomfilename.xlsx";

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpfilename));
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.UseBinary = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
int i = 0;
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
do { i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); mStream.Write(bytes, 0, i); } while (i != 0);
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", @"attachment;filename=" + filename);
context.Response.BinaryWrite(mStream.GetBuffer());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually telling FtpWebRequest which file to download, ftpfilename only contains the FTP server URL. Try modifying this line:

```cs
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpfilename));
```

To:

```cs
var requestUri = new Uri(ftpfilename + filename);
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
```

I would suggest extracting your FtpWebRequest code out into a separate method with a signature like `public byte[] FtpDownloadBinary(Uri fromUri)` which you can implement and test separately, then you can pass the result of that method into `context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);`

== edit ==

Here is an example method that FTP downloads a given binary URL:

```cs
string username = "anonymous";
string password = "anonymous@example.org";

public byte[] FtpDownloadBinary(Uri fromUri)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fromUri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.KeepAlive = true;

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You can test that this works by saving the result to a local file on your system with something like the code below, the resultant file can be opened with 7-Zip, WinRAR, WinZip, etc.:

```cs
string ftpfilename = "ftp://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ls-lR.gz"; //1.7MB example
var requestUri = new Uri(ftpfilename);
var fileBytes = FtpDownloadBinary(requestUri);

using (var fileStream = new FileStream("ls-lR.gz", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    fileStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the actual filename in the ftpfilename string... It is present in my actual code, though.  And thank you for your suggestion, I'll try that - but the code I specified works correctly for me on all other file types except xlsx.

Comment: Still not working for excel "xlsx" files.  I'm able to download these files directly from 
 the ftp server no problem, which tells me that the files themselves are not corrupted.  It's just the actual download using this method that corrupts the file for some reason.

Comment: XLSX files aren't anything special, essentially they're a series of XML files packaged up inside a .zip archive. You can see this for yourself by renaming one from Foo.xlsx to Foo.zip and opening it in 7-Zip, WinRAR or WinZip, or even just browse its contents with a modern Windows Explorer. I'm afraid I don't have any further suggestion for you, other than the possibility that Microsoft .NET's FTP client may not actually be compatible with your FTP server. You may need to try an alternate FTP library such as [WinSCP's .NET automation library](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

Comment: @aspnet123 Actually, I just had another thought... Before `request.GetResponse()` you could add `request.UsePassive = true;` This will encourage the FTP client to use PASV mode for transfers, which may be a thing required by your particular FTP server.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, still no luck though.  However, I'm looking at the file size of the downloaded file compared to the actual size of the file - and the downloaded size is almost twice as large.  Could this be the issue?  And if so, do you have any ideas how to rectify that?

Comment: Definitely an issue, though I don't know what could be causing that. If it were 33% bigger than it should be I would suspect base64 encoding having been applied - that takes takes every 3 binary bytes and converts them to 4 characters from the base64 dictionary, thus expanding the stream by 33%. I don't know what would be doubling its size, though.